# How to plot x,y coordinates of item on a image in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I need to place/plot a pin(Small image to point the parts of person) on a image(For example: A image of person).

I am getting x,y,height,width values from server for a specific pin and i am creating one div element for each pin and assigning x,y,height,width values.

In Javascript, i am calculating view scale value in below mentioned way and multiply view scale with x,y,width,height and assign it into pin div element.

```
const screenwidth = screen.width;
const screenheight = screen.height;

viewscale = Math.min(screenwidth / mainImagewidth, screenheight / mainImageheight);
```

I am not able to place the pin on exact position of main image. Please help me if someone has idea of this logic.

Update:
Please find below the explanation through image.
[image]

Red Color rectangle is the screen. Green is the main image, let's say human image. Black color rectangle is a pin to describe a part in human image. I am getting x,y coordinates for this black colored rect pin from server.

Comment: Do you need this image to fill up the screen width?

Comment: No. I need place this pin image as per it's x,y,width,height on main image. @cnexans

Comment: Can you at least post an example of the result you expect on Codepen, Plunkr or any similar site, so it's clear for everybody? Even a MS Paint (RIP) drawing may suffice.

Comment: Sorry for late response.I have attached image with more explanation. @Denialos

Comment: @AndroidKid Just added my answer based on the understanding of this issue. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood this correctly, here's a possible demo solution:

First, define a config for your pin:

```
const pinConfig = {
  width: 45,
  height: 45,
  offsetLeft: 40,
  offsetTop: 75
};
```

Define a simple key/value map for getting the correct size type (width or height) when given an offset type (left or top):

```
const offsetTypeToSizeDimensionMap = {
  left: 'width',
  top: 'height'
};
```

Use a simple fn that calculates offset position relative to size. `size / 2` because we need to compensate for the size of the pin, so positioning is based on the center of the element.

```
const calcRelativeOffsetPos = (offsetPos, size) => offsetPos - (size / 2);
```

Here's a style attribute string generating fn, accepts an object (our `pinConfig` above, basically):

```
const generateStylesString = (stylesConfig) => {
  return Object.keys(stylesConfig).map((styleProp) => {
    if (styleProp.includes('offset')){
      const stylePropName = styleProp.split('offset')[1].toLowerCase();
      const relativeSizeTypeByOffsetType = offsetTypeToSizeDimensionMap[stylePropName];
      const calculatedRelativeOffsetPos = calcRelativeOffsetPos(stylesConfig[styleProp], stylesConfig[relativeSizeTypeByOffsetType]);
      return stylePropName + ': ' + calculatedRelativeOffsetPos + 'px; ';
    }
    return styleProp + ': ' + stylesConfig[styleProp] + 'px; ';
  }).join('');
};
```

Finally, set `style` attr to `.child-parent` node:

```
document.querySelector('.child-image').setAttribute('style', generateStylesString(pinConfig));
```

Here's an example on Codepen: https://codepen.io/Inlesco/pen/xLwjLy?editors=1010

If you need the React way, it's easy - just concat the generated inline styles string to a JSX element when mapping out the elements and that's it.

Feel free to provide feedback, so we can improve this :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was useful to me. But in my case i found the major issue in coordinates coming from server itself so corrected it. Now everything works fine in my existing code itself. thanks for your time.